# tsql query not working in mysql

Tags: mysql, t-sql, casting, partitioning

I currently have the following script working fine in TSQL:

```
select v.ratings as [Rating], COUNT(*) as 'total', 
    CAST(count(*)*100.0/tot as decimal(12,1)) as 'percent'
from (select (case when Ratings = 5 then '5'
                when Ratings = 6 then '6'
                when Ratings = 7 then '7'
                end) as Ratings,
                COUNT(*) over (partition by NULL) as tot
            from vHighPerformance) v
group by v.Ratings, v.tot
```

This same script does not work in MYSQL. It gives the following:
*1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[Rating], COUNT(*) as 'total', CAST(count(*)*100.0/tot as decimal(12,1)) as '' at line 1*

Does anyone have any advice on translating this to mysql? As my research is falling short. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a mysql installation to try, but this should work:

```
select v.ratings as Rating, COUNT(*) as total, 
    CAST(count(*)*100.0/tot as decimal(12,1)) as percent
from (select (case when Ratings = 5 then '5'
                when Ratings = 6 then '6'
                when Ratings = 7 then '7'
                end) as Ratings,
                (SELECT COUNT(*) FRMO vHighPerformance) as tot
            from vHighPerformance) v
group by v.Ratings, v.tot
```